# Codeigniter - Data for database from Input class or Form Validation class?

Tags: database, validation, codeigniter

I'm building my first CodeIgniter app - and have a registration form. I'm using the built-in form validation class to validate the data, and am at the point of adding that data to the database.

Should I be taking that data from the form validation class or from the input class ($this->input->post('username'))?

I'm guessing the correct way is from the input class, but just wanted to be sure. If that's the case, if there any prepping of the data I need to do before it gets inserted into the database such as 'trim'?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you would get the data from the input class. Operations such as `trim()` can be done using the form validation library by adding the `trim` to the set of rules for validation. When the validation is done, your data is ready to be inserted to the database.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise form validation rules prepped the data in the input class also - I thought they were kept as seperate data objects. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've always used `$this->input->post('lalal');` and found it to work since the validation is already done when i use the values. But you could also use the `set_value('lalal');` helper function, this is particularly useful if you found an error but don't want the user to entery every form field again but just the one that was faulty.

Your prepping of the data should be in the validation rules, you can add any php-functions that take one argument, ie trim, also you can call on the helper functions CI offers if they are loaded when the validation happens. And you have the built-in's that CI has with the validation class.

For more info check out: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#thecontroller

Comment: Thanks Anton - If I could mark both answers as correct I would!! :)